# Rails method evaluating user input

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I’m trying to check for specific entry condition combinations “entry_conditions”  when a user submits a form.

If the user enters these exact values for either of the entry_conditions (a or b), I would like “meets_any_entry_conditions?” to be true.
But I’m struggling with the structure.

```
def entry_conditions
 condition a = [fielda: 6, fieldb: 6, fieldc: 6]
 condition b = [fielde: 10, fieldf: 10, fieldg: 10]
end


def meets_any_entry_conditions?
  entry_conditions.any? 
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
def entry_conditions
  [{fielda: 6, fieldb: 6, fieldc: 6},{fielde: 10, fieldf: 10, fieldg: 10}]
end

def meets_any_entry_conditions?
  entry_conditions.each do |condition|
    passed = true
    condition.each do |k, v|
      passed = false unless send(k) == v
      break unless passed
    end
    return true if passed
  end
  false
end
```